# Как сделать, чтобы при заходе на поддомен открывался сайт из конкретной папки на сайте? Но при этом, чтобы когда я вводил url папки, выводилась 404?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

У меня сайт-портфолио. И я хочу свои крупные пет-проекты разместить на поддоменах.

Я создал в корне сайта папку subdomains. И положил туда свои проекты. Например, проект site_1.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы открывался конкретный сайт при заходе на поддомен, например, при заходе на `site_1.my-site.ru` открывался сайт из папки `my-site.ru/subdomains/site_1`? Но при этом, чтобы когда я вводил url `my-site.ru/subdomains/site_1`, мне выводилась 404? Не хочу, чтобы проекты можно было открыть из папки напрямую.

Comment: Может не делать `subdomains` внутри основной `htdocs`.
Там пути должны очень гибко настраиваться в конфиге апача

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду. Можно чуть поподробнее? subdomains надо на уровень (каталог) выше? И как дальше настраивать?

Можно ли настроить на shared хостинге?

Comment: берите vps <2$/мес, наше время дороже. У вас же и backend наверно будет с собственным кодом, а на shared другая версия чего-нибудь и опять проблемы из ничего.

Comment: `<VirtualHost ... DocumentRoot "/kuda-ugodno/htdocs"`

Comment: и (если памяти хватит) можно там `docker` поднять и разворачивать вообще любые сервера легко